# How long does IBM's Watson Dialog Service retain conversation and client details?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-dialog

I'm just getting started with Watson Dialog service and I'm trying to ensure that I don't allow my users to attempt to resume a conversation with the bot if their conversation session is no longer valid. Is there an expiration on Dialog conversations at all? Or does IBM simply store conversations forever?

**EDIT:**

If there is a method to determine whether a Dialog Conversation has expired, please provide a link to documentation, or an example, of said method.

Answer (score 0):

If a user returns and starts a new session, then that is a new conversation. Conversations do time out. I've only worked on enterprise engagements, so the time out varies. I believe default is 30 minutes, but that may change for Bluemix.

A better solution however is to have your application on determining it's time out, to dump the users profile variables to storage. When they return you can rebuild the relevant part of the conversation.

Comment: "A better solution however is to have your application on determining it's time out" Can you elaborate on this part of your answer, it seems like there's a typo, but if I'm following you I believe that you're suggesting that there is a way to determine if a conversation has expired? If that's the case please provide the method for determining whether a conversation is expired.